# jquery find versus context selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Having the following html snippet

```
<div class="something">
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div class="somethingElse">
    <p>some other text</p>
</div>
```

I think the following jquery snippets are identical (will have the same result):

```
$(".something").find("p").css("border", "1px solid red");

$("p", ".something").css("border", "1px solid red");
```

My question is, whether one snippet is better than the other and should be used

Comment: Why don't you use $(".something > p")? That's pure CSS.

Comment: @Xr: It would be rather `$(".something p")`.

Comment: $(".something p") is actually the slowest method available because, apparently, jQuery will search from right to left, finding first all p elements in the document, then filtering them for the .something ancestor.  $(".something").find("p") is the fastest, as per my answer below.

Comment: @Xr. jQuery is still a javascript, nothing more. This sintaxis just looks like css, there is no magic behind it that uses native css mechanics inside javascript, as i understand.

Comment: @MaxYari Indeed. But I think it's useful to keep one syntax rather than multiply the choices. For your information, JQuery is based on a selector library named Sizzle: http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The calls are not identical.

According Brandon Aaron, who apparently worked on jQuery, and also according to the live tests [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-2), the find method is always faster.  See results in the screenshot below.  Please comment if I am missing something.

With a 10% or greater difference in speed, depending on browser, it definitely seems worth using find.

Further explanation at Brandon's site is [here](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery).

[image: Results of performance comparison between jQuery context and jQuery find method]

Comment: I added a test for using the context the "right way" according to the above-mentioned article - by supplying a DOM Node for the second argument. Ironically, it's even slower: http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-2/3

Comment: your chart show the opposite from what you said. the red line is the context and it seems to be faster than the blue line(the find() method) Am i missing somthing?

Comment: sorry,my confusion...at first glance it seems the opposite, but the x axis is: operations per second - so after undestanding that it makes sense

Answer (score 22):

Both calls are identical. The latter call is translated into the former one. If you want to omit the translation step, use the former one.

Comment: Might be obvious, but I am uncertain: Is this the same, when the outer selector is already a jQuery object? Like $sth.find('p') is slightly faster than $('p', $sth.)?

Comment: Live tests posted in my answer seem to demonstrate that the find method is always faster.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @BrianFinkel `$(selector, context)` is ‘translated’ into `$(context).find(selector)` internally. That translation takes the additional time.

Comment: Here is the relevant part of the jQuery (1.10.2) source, for the curious: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.10.2/src/core.js#L175-L183

Comment: These calls are not the same... please see tests below

Comment: @Gumbo if one of the calls takes _additional time_, how can you say both calls are identical? One takes X time the other takes Y. That doesn't look identical (X <> Y) to me.

Answer (score 11):

I can think of one use case where using the `context` form might be preferable - in the case where the context is contained in a variable which might be null.

For example:

```
// Only affect matching items that are descendants of '#parent'
do_something( $( '#parent' ) );
// Affect all matching items
do_something();

function do_something( $parent_element ){
  $( '.child', $parent_element ).each( function(){ } );
}
```

The second time `do_something()` is called, if we had used `$parent_element.find()` it would have failed, whereas in this example, if `$parent_element` is undefined or empty the context is null, thus: the entire document.

Admittedly this is an edge case, but it just came up in something I was working on, so thought I'd put it here for posterity.

Answer (score 7):

Find is better, by 40%:

http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-2/13

Note the difference:

```
$myDiv = $("myDiv")
myDiv = "#myDiv"
```

when passing `$myDiv`, the jQuery element as the context, its about 10% slower than $.find.
when passing in `#myDiv`, the jQuery selector as the context, its 40% slower than $.find.

$.find > context.