# remove parent element but keep the child element using jquery in HTML

Tags: jquery

From the below HTML i want to remove the div and H2 tags but keep the UL tag using jquery.

Please advise how i can achieve this

```
<div class="row">
    <h2><asp:Literal ID="categoryTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h2>
    <ul class="tree js-catTree" id="treeContainer" runat="server"></ul>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$('.row').replaceWith(function() {
 return $('ul', this);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/WkmWb/)

Comment: Nice solution. Amit if you want to keep what's inside `<h2>` use  `return $('ul, h2 *', this);`

Comment: `$('ul', this)` is functionally the same as `$(this).find('ul')`, right? I havent seen that syntax before.

Comment: @Jeff not quite, according to this, `find` is faster, although YMMV. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342282/54975

Comment: Maybe **functionally** was the wrong adverb. I was just trying to figure out if they return the same things. Sounds like they do. Thanks for expanding my world a tiny bit.

Comment: @Jeff in that case, yes :) They both find an element starting at a specific point in the tree.

Answer (score 22):

I stumbled across this page when simply trying to remove a parent element *(whilst still keeping the children)* - just in case it's useful to others I found [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to be exactly what I needed. For me it was a simple find-an-element-and-unwrap:

```
$('.target-child').unwrap();
```

However the addition of the h2 removal in this case makes things a little bit more involved:

```
$('.row h2').siblings('ul').unwrap().end().remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8uQ8/

The above should be more optimal as it doesn't rely on the use of an anonymous function creation and call.

Comment: @AndreasM. ~ hmm, odd; pretty certain it used to work but can't find a previous version of jQuery where it does atm. Cheers for the heads up, have updated with a version that does 100% work, along with a demo fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) function ?

This will remove the element (visually) but keep its code in a variable, then you can append it into another parent.

Comment: He'd better insert the `ul` after its parent and, later, remove the parent from DOM.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Silvain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515437/sylvain) said, you could `detach` the element and save the reference to a variable.

```
var $ul = $('.row h2').siblings('ul').detach();
```

Then you could insert the `ul` after its parent and, later, remove the parent from DOM:

```
$('.row').after($ul).remove();
```