# Removing only the parent element in the DOM JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, parent

I am running out of ideas. I have an issue here where I need to remove only the parent element while preserving the child element.

```
<div class="remove_this_only">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>I want to get preserved</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

the resultant output should be

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>I want to get preserved</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you remove the `<td>` or the `<tr>` (not sure which you're talking about) you'll have invalid HTML markup.

Comment: <html>
 <div class="remove_this_only">
   <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>I want to get preserved</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
</html>. I want to remove the div

Comment: I've added an answer, but I'm not sure what context you would be using it in.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936887/remove-parent-element-but-keep-the-child-element-using-jquery-in-html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A straight forward way:

```
var div = $(".remove_this_only");
var tmp = div.children().clone();
var parent = div.parent();
div.remove();
tmp.appendTo(parent);
```

A fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cb9sb/

Comment: -1 This has bugs.  If the element to remove is not at the end of it's parent, then you get your code in the wrong order: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/cb9sb/1/

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:**

Sounds like you want to remove the `<div>` you added to the question.

Just select the `<table>` and use the [`unwrap()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method.

```
$('div > table').unwrap();
```

Of course the selector will vary based on your ***actual*** markup.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VyJv3/ *(the styled `div` has been removed)*

---

**Original answer:**

The way it is, you'll be removing an element that is required for a table.

If you were hoping to remove the `<td>`, you'll have text node as a child of a `<tr>`. You can do that.

If your HTML was like this:

```
<html>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span>I want to get preserved</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...and you wanted to get rid of the `<span>`, you could use the [`unwrap()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method.

```
$('td > span').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: love this solution, rather than '$("table")' selector '$(".remove_this_only table")' would probably be the best.

Comment: @Dustin: Thanks. I have a feeling that the class doesn't actually exist on the element, but rather that OP is using it to point out the `div` in the question. I do agree that if there is a class, or some other designation in the actual HTML, that it should be used in the selector.

Comment: I like too ! wrap() is also usefull

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you mean.

I think this is what your looking for:

```
$("td").closest("table").unwrap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Detach() does not work for your case ?

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

You can also use the html() methods to extract the source code.

Algorithm :

1. Detach inner block
2. Remove block to destroy
3. Attach the inner block at proper place.

Comment: Detach() removes the inner blocks also

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to take what you want to remain and append it to the parent of the element you want to remove. Then remove the element which you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the whole structure and just keep the pieces you want:

```
$('html').clone().appendTo('tmp');
```

Comment: How would this remove the `<div>` element, and what is `'tmp'` supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more complete in my example. wong2's answer explains what I was getting at.  If you make a copy of the html node, you can manipulate it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take the contents of the `div`, and replace the `div` with that:

```
$(".remove_this_only").replaceWith($(".remove_this_only").html());
```

Comment: This will work, but keep in mind that it removes all associated jQuery data like event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inner = $(".remove_this_only").html();
var parent = $(".remove_this_only").parent();
$(".remove_this_only").remove();
parent.append(inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answers in action:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/PqDCH/
- http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/PqDCH/3/
- http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/PqDCH/4/

---

```
//option 1
var $table = $('table');
$table.parent().before($table).remove();

//option 2
var $toRemove = $('.remove_this_only');
$toRemove.before($toRemove.children()).remove();

//option 3
$('table').unwrap();
```

**Notes:**

- `append`, `before`, and some other jQuery functions do 'detachment' automatically.
- These are all really short, which makes them awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution Marked As Answer is Not Exact As Mentioned In Comment..

here is an Exact Solution to get the first children and the replace parent 
with the child

```
var child = $("#entry-longdesc").children().first().clone();
$("#entry-longdesc").replaceWith(child);
```

this will only remove the parent tag and keep your child dom as it is

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be the unwrap() jQuery method, with an added selector to the parent element you want to remove. So in your case:

```
$('table').unwrap('.remove_this_only');
```

Note: if you don't add the '.remove_this_only' selector, it could unwrap more parent elements than you want. Alternatively, if you want to make sure you specifically target the "table" element only in the '.remove_this_only' element, you can do the following:

```
 $('.remove_this_only').find('table').unwrap('.remove_this_only');
```