# jQuery : Removing parent tag not the child of that parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i am trying to remove parent tag,
but removing parent tag should not remove their child element.
The child should get attached previous tag

Below is the code:

`<div class="mask">`
   `<ul id="TickerT" class="news">`
      **`<ul class="tweet_list">`**

        `<li class="first odd">`
`<span class="tweet_time">about 8 minutes ago</a></span>`
`<span class="tweet_join"></span>`
`<span class="tweet_text">test test…</a></span>`
`</li>`
      **`</ul>`**
    `</ul>` 
  `</div>` 
`</div>`

There are at-least 5 `<li>` and now i want to delete `<ul class="tweet_list">`.
I have tried it with jQuery's [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) but no result.

Here's the code i have used from a site
var jj = $("ul.tweet_list").contents()
$(".tweet_list").replaceWith(jj);

But this didn't worked.

What i wanted is i want to remove `<ul class="tweet_list">` but not `<li>` of that `<ul>`.

**Help appreciated, Thanks..**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936887/remove-parent-element-but-keep-the-child-element-using-jquery-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jj = $("ul.tweet_list").html()
$("ul.tweet_list").replaceWith(jj)
```

There is no content method on jquery. Try the html method.

Answer (score 5):

You can call the [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method on your list item:

```
$("ul.tweet_list > li").unwrap();
```

This will remove the `.tweet_list` `<ul>` element and reparent the `<li>` element (and its siblings, if any) under the `#TickerT` `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method:

```
$('.tweet_list').children().unwrap();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2NMU/)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the `.html()` content and the parent ul of the list you want to delete into a variable and then add the `.html()` to the parent ul.