# How to convert HTML DOM structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have different requirement for my webpage. For that I need to change the DOM elements. I will have the html from server through AJAX. Html is come from server for different pages is different. Like,

```
<h1> Some text </h1>
Text out of tags
<div> 
 <p> Text in div </p>
 <img src="some-image.jpg" />
</div>
<p> <a href="#"> Some other text </a> </p>
<p> Some other text </p>
<img src="some-image.png" />
```

Something like that.

**When it appears in webpage, It would be like,**

Some text Text out of tags

Text in div **An Image**

Some other text

Some other text

**Another Image**

So, what I need is, I want to convert the above HTML DOM structure as follows by using Javascript or jQuery.

```
<p> Some text Text out of tags Text in div</p>
<img src="some-image.jpg" />
<p> Some other text </p>
<p> Some other text </p>
<img src="some-image.png" />
```

I just want text through `<p>` tags and images through `<img>` tags. I don't require remaining all other stuff.

If it is possible, please help me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using angularjs?

Comment: Yes. I use angularJS.

Comment: p tag cannot contain block level element inside it including itself. so your html need to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`$("<selector>").contents().unwrap();`

with all the element you want to remove.
For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1, div, a').contents().unwrap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> <h1> Some text </h1> </p>
<div> <img src="some-image.jpg" /> </div>
<p> <a href="#"> Some other text </a> </p>
<p> Some other text </p>
<img src="some-image.png" />
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, just one tiny note to add to make the code slightly more succinct, you can pass multiple selectors in to the jquery function: `$('h1, div, a').contents().unwrap();`

Comment: Thanks for your improvement, bro

Comment: It is worked. I used `$("<selector> *").contents().unwrap();` But when I take html from `$("<selector>")`, it returns html is like, `Text out of tags` as I have written in question. Can I manipulate that HTML string with that content in paragraph?

Comment: you could check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836633/jquery-wrap-all-unwrapped-text-in-p-tags) to have more information about wrap all unwrap text :D

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question [remove parent element but keep the child element using jquery in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936887/remove-parent-element-but-keep-the-child-element-using-jquery-in-html)

use [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) and return the element you want

Comment: For single child, it is ok. If I have more than one child, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate/edit the DOM structure received from the server. To hide certain `<div>` or `<p>` elements, try following :

```
document.getElementById("divWithImage").style.display = "none";
                                                        ^^^^^^
```

Of course this will hide everything inside, so you should get hold of the inside contents like `<img>` and inject them again in the DOM at desired location.