# Apply numerical class to child elements

Tags: jquery, class, numbers

I can't seem to figure out how I would go about adding a class to a group of elements inside their parent.

**Example:**

```
<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail"></a>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail"></a>
</div>
```

**I would like it to look like so:**

```
<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail group1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail group1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail group1"></a>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail group2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail group2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail group2"></a>
</div>
```

**I tried something like:**

```
$("div.Block a").attr("class", function (arr) {
  return "group" + arr;
});
```

but that returns the class inside the blocks to all have different numbers instead of in groups. Maybe something like using that on the parent div and somehow copying the master div class to each of its children after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the following code

```
$("div.block").each(function(index){
  $(this).find('a').addClass("group" + (index+1));
})
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I couldn't seem to get James's to work I ended up going with this version of the code instead. Yes I see I had the class wrong in my example, but was just a typo when I was writing the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.block").each(function(i){
    $(this).find("a").addClass("group" + (i + 1));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.block').each(function(idx) {
    $('a', this).addClass('group' + (idx + 1));
});​
```

Comment: I typically prefer this notation rather than `.find`

Comment: In general, which is better `$('a', this)` or `$(this).find(`?

Comment: @vega They're basically the same.  Probably just use whichever you find clearer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342282/jquery-find-versus-context-selection

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
//     v-- Note: your div class is block not Block.
$("div.block").each (function (idx) { 
    $(this).find('a').addClass('group' + (idx+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the divs and use the index from that iterator:

```
​$(".block").each(function(i,e){
    $("a",e).addClass("group" + (i+1));
})​​​
```

Note the use of addClass instead of attr as well.
Also note using the e (element) as context for "a" selector