# jQuery select change event get selected option

Tags: jquery, events

I bound an event on the change event of my select elements with this:

```
$('select').on('change', '', function (e) {

});
```

How can I access the element which got selected when the change event occurs?

Answer (score 555, accepted):

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    ....
});
```

Comment: What does the $("selector", this) syntax mean? I have a general idea, but I'm not totally sure

Comment: @JoshWillik with `$("selector", this)` you are finding all `selector` elements inside `this`'s context. Writing  `$("selector", this)` is almost the same than  `$(this).find('selector')`

Comment: Is there a documentation for this somewhere? I looked around the jQuery docs and didn't find anything.

Comment: @JoshWillik: since ``$()`` is an alias of ``jQuery()``, you can find the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ The signature stated there is obviously ``jQuery( selector [, context ] )``.

@Bellash: if it's "almost the same", what is the difference? Or what is faster? I prefer ``.find()`` since this is more OO IMO...

Comment: How to check in case of multiple select?

Comment: @Neal get the changed option for a multi select.

Comment: @Hemant_Negi Hmm I do not know off-hand, that might make a good stack overflow question if it has not been asked already :-) Let me know if you find the answer :-D

Comment: @AdrianFöder For you and other people looking for it, `.find()` is around 10% faster according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9046288/2767703

Answer (score 93):

You can use the [jQuery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method

```
 $('select').change(function () {
     var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
     var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
     var textSelected   = optionSelected.text();
 });
```

The above solution works perfectly but I choose to add the following code for them willing to get the clicked option. It allows you get the selected option even when this select value has not changed. (Tested with Mozilla only)

```
    $('select').find('option').click(function () {
     var optionSelected = $(this);
     var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
     var textSelected   = optionSelected.text();
   });
```

Comment: Binding to `option` events is a risky proposition, particularly on mobile devices. For example, Webkit doesn't support this event correctly: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5284

Comment: Ok cool! As I said, the second solution is not supported in many browsers!

Answer (score 21):

#### Delegated Alternative

In case anyone is using the [delegated approach](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for their listener, use `e.target` (it will refer to the select element).

```
$('#myform').on('change', 'select', function (e) {
    var val = $(e.target).val();
    var text = $(e.target).find("option:selected").text(); //only time the find is required
    var name = $(e.target).attr('name');
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/slicedtoad/mepn038v/1/)**

Comment: +1 because this is what i want, but when i tried this locally, its not working .Only work at jsfiddle, what are the CDN do i have to add?

Answer (score 12):

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>


$('#selectId').on('change', function () {
     var selectVal = $("#selectId option:selected").val();
});
```

First create a `select option`. After that using `jquery` you can get current selected value when user change `select option` value.

Comment: can you please share more detail explanation of your answer ?

Comment: @MostafizurRahman my code very easy that's why i wrote only code.

Comment: simple and fewer code thanks, I'm looking for this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I find this shorter and cleaner. Besides, you can iterate through selected items if there are more than one;

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
     var selectedValue = this.selectedOptions[0].value;
     var selectedText  = this.selectedOptions[0].text;
});
```

Comment: `selectedOptions` is not available in all browsers.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler which ones? any source?

Comment: I copied your code to IE 11 and got an error. I ended up with `this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ]`. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) says is supported by Firefox from 26, IE No support.

Comment: It is supported by all browsers except IE.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#_SelectID').change(function () {
        var SelectedText = $('option:selected',this).text();
        var SelectedValue = $('option:selected',this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Another and short way to get value of selected value,

```
$('#selectElement').on('change',function(){
   var selectedVal = $(this).val();
                       ^^^^  ^^^^ -> presents #selectElement selected value 
                         |
                         v
               presents #selectElement, 
});
```

Comment: if this is the case, why wont "var selectedVal=$("#selectElement").val()" work¿

Comment: The case is getting value when change event emitted on select element. Value wouldn't be updated when select changes if you do like that.

Answer (score 3):

This can also work fine

```js
(function(jQuery) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select_menu").change(function() {
      var selectedOption = $("#select_menu").val()
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

See official API documentation
https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

This good works:

```
$( "select" ).on('change',function() {
  var str = "";
  // For multiple choice
  $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
    str += $( this ).val() + " "; 
  });
});
```

and

```
$( "select" ).on('change',function() {
  // For unique choice
  var selVal = $( "select option:selected" ).val(); 
});
```

and be easy for unique choice

```
var SelVal = $( "#idSelect option:selected" ).val();
```