# Jquery change the variable value if select field change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

oke i have select field

```
<select id="select" required name="bank" >
  <option value="cash">Cash</option>
  <option value="debit">Debit Card</option>
  <option value="cc">Credit Card</option>
</select>
```

and the  text field to show price

```
<input type="text" id="sub_total" name="sub_total">
<input type="text" id="fee" name="fee">
<input type="text" id="sum" name="total">
```

and the javascript

```
var total = 0;
var fees = 0;
var total_fees = fees + total;

$("#sub_total").val(total);
$("#fee").val(fees);
$("#sum").val(total_fees);
```

so the point is i want to change the "fees" value from "0" to "0.1 or what ever i want" if select credit card

the pseudecode is

if select cc
 var fees = '0.1';
else
 var fees = '0';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery select change event get selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750307/jquery-select-change-event-get-selected-option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('#select').change(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "cc")
      {
         $('#fee').val(0.1);
      }
   });
```

Comment: FIXED - Sorry this is wrong, you should be comparing the "#select" value to "cc" - which is the value of that select option, not "Credit Card" which is the label.

Comment: @Neaox oops.. thanks for catching that..in the pressure to answer in SO, phew.

Comment: @derylihs nice.. glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator to switch between 0 and .1 based on the `select` value

```
var fees = ($("#select").val() === "cc" ? 0.1 : 0);
```

You should wrap this in a function, and bind the select element to this function on change.

e.g. :

```
var sel = $("#select");

function setValue() {
  var total = 0,
      fees = (sel.val() === "cc" ? 0.1 : 0); // ternary

  $("#sub_total").val(total);
  $("#fee").val(fees);
  $("#sum").val(fees + total); // sum
}

setValue(); // call function
sel.bind('change', setValue);  // bind function to onchange of the select element
```

Comment: @derylihs is using jQuery it would make sense to provide an answer that uses jQuery.

Comment: @Neaox take note on the javascript tag