# jQuery val() not working properly on dynamic <select> with Aloha Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, aloha-editor

I am creating a dynamic `<select>` element through jQuery `append()` function, but I cant seem to get the correct selected value. I always get the first option, which is 1. I am trying to configure the Aloha Editor, which probably has something to do with the issue.

This is the select element, appended in a sidebar.

```
$('.aloha-sidebar-inner').append('<select id="columns"><option value="1">1 Column</option><option value="2">2 Columns</option><option value="3">3 Columns</option><option value="4">4 Columns</option></select>').trigger('create');
```

As mentioned I use Aloha Editor, so the jquery looks like this:

```
    Aloha.ready(function() {
          $('.aloha-sidebar-inner').append('<button id="add-section" class="btn aloha-sidebar-btn sidebar-item" type="button" onclick="addSection(document.getElementById(\'articles\').value);">Add Section</button>');
          $('.aloha-sidebar-inner').append('<p>Number of Columns:</p>');
          $('.aloha-sidebar-inner').append('<select id="articles" class="sidebar-item"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option></select>');
    });

        function addSection() {     
          var idCounter = 0;
          alert($('#articles').val());
};
```

The alert windows keeps returning the value 1. Maybe there is an issue because I create the select element dynamically?

I have tried using `$( "#columns option:selected" ).val();` but still nothing. I even tried using `text()`, but still nothing; `alert` keeps returning the first option.

I also tried using `$('#add-section').click` or `$('#articles').change` listeners but they don't seem to respond.

Comment: Create a working demo of your problem on http://jsfiddle.net, please. The first option *should* be selected by default, so it's not clear why you're expecting it to be different than that.

Comment: And IDs are unique, right?!

Comment: Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/uJur9/1/ How are you alerting? onclick or onchange etc?

Comment: What are you expecting the alert to show if not `1` ?

Comment: are you expecting this http://jsfiddle.net/EnJz5/

Comment: It's probably a duplicate ID issue. He has another `select` with the same `#columns` id

Comment: I tried a few different IDs just in case, but no use. I also tried using onclick="addSection(document.getElementById('articles').value);", still nothing. My source code seems to be correct since it works on jFiddle, but it wont seem to work on my project. Any ideas what the issue might be?? I will update the question, so you can see everything I have tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

[I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750307/jquery-select-change-event-get-selected-option/20030786#20030786) this question last:

```
    $('#columns').change(function () {
    var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
    var textSelected   = optionSelected.text();
  });
```

Comment: It's my pleasure DEUTSCHWULF!

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected columns use the below code

```
$('#columns').change(
    function()
    {
        alert($('#columns').val());
    });
```

fiddle : jsfiddle.net/EnJz5