# JQuery Mobile: when an option is selected: do something. (show/hide element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, html-select

i have been struggling with this for the past 6 hours but i can't find a solution. I'm using jquery mobile 1.4.5. I have a select with 5 options. They are all selected and when one is deselected i want to do something. So i'd like to get the id of the deselected option. This is my html:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-icon="false" data-divider-theme="b">
<li data-role="list-divider"><h2>Upcoming events <button data-role="none" class="filter" type="submit">
<i class="fa fa-filter"></i> 
</button><button onclick="hide()">Hide social</button><button onclick="show()">show social</button><h2></li>
<div class="ui-field-contain sixtynine" data-position-to="window">
<select name="select-custom-19" id="filter-type" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Filter events</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected" id="f-1">family</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected" id="f-2">friends</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected" id="f-3">business</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected" id="f-4">social</option>
    <option value="5" selected="selected" id="f-5">private</option>
</select>
</div>
<li data-role="list-divider"><h2>Today<h2></li>
// irrelevant
```

The "hide social" and "show social" work. And i want to be able to have their behavior inside the select. So instead of 2 buttons (1 showing, 1 hiding) I have a select option when checked shows the element and when unchecked hides it. Idem for the other 4 options.

So how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `on('change')` function provided by jquery:

```
$('#filter-type').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    console.log(optionSelected);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    ....
});
```

[jquery select change event get selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750307/jquery-select-change-event-get-selected-option)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried it and it doesn't seem to work.
   `$('#filter-type').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    console.log(optionSelected);
 alert(optionSelected);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    alert(valueSelected);
});`

Comment: Think about it.  What element are you attaching the handler to?  What does `this` mean inside that function?

Comment: You're attaching the handler to the `#filter-type` element - which is the `select`.  The `select` doesn't have a `value`.  The `select` contains `option` elements, which *do* have `value`s.  You've grabbed all the selected options and put them in the `optionSelected` variable.  Inspect that a little in the console.  Btw: avoid `alert(value)` - log things to the console, where you can right-click -> store as global variable, and then you can interact with them.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. So how would i access the option(s) that is/are selected? And when you say console, do you mean the one in google chrome? And is it normal that even 'alert(optionSelected)' didn't do anything?

Comment: `alert` can only show you a string in a box.  There's FAAR more to Javascript than strings :)  All modern browsers have a "developer tools" area with various tools for showing network traffic, debugging etc, but yet - Chrome is a good choice.  F12 or Ctrl-Shift-I or menu -> more tools -> developer tools.  As a coder I have this open in every window 100% of the time.

Comment: So now i have done this: `$('#filter-type').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    console.log(optionSelected);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    console.log(valueSelected);
});` and nothing appeared in the console. Am i doing something wrong or is their and underlying issue?

Comment: Are you changing the selected options?  Where are you putting that code?    If you're not working with any structure to your application, just make sure you put that code in a `<script>` tag at the *bottom of your `<body>` element*, and put it inside a `$(document).on('ready', function () { ... });`

Comment: I click the options and nothing happens. I'm working inside a listview in a jquery mobile content-div. The code is as you said at the bottom inside a script tag inside a $(document).on.... function.

Comment: What happens if you put `console.log(1)` as the first line inside that handler, then reload the page and click the options?  Do you see a `1` appear in the console when you click?  I'm sorry but I can't be much more help without seeing your actual code / being in a seat next to you.

Comment: Doing this: `$(document).on('ready', function () {
 $('#filter-type').on('change', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
 });
});` _nothing_ happens. I think there might be an underlying problem.

Comment: Play in the console.  Type lines like `document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="pie">POTATO</div>';` and `$('.pie').on('click', function () {console.log("WORKS");});` then click the div and see what shows up in the console.  Make sure you're using jQuery and not the browser `$`.  You really have to investigate the environment you're running in - and the console is the best place for that.  Play with it - lots.  Get familiar with it.

Comment: I'll do that. And i think my problem might be due to the fact that the select menu is in a jquery popup. Looking all over the internet i haven't found a solution for it yet.
With the 'hide social' and 'show social' i have no problems and i can log to the console. But it's with the selectt menu that i have problems.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction to learn more about this?