# Adding form fields according to drop down selections of the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

What i'm trying to achieve is adding input fields relevant to user's input on the drop down selection.So then next a text field appears, to the selection.I want to keep on appending those selection input fields.

Following is what i have tried so far,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    $("#volvo").click(function(){
        $("option").append("<li>Volvo: <input type="text" name="volvotype" ></li>");
    });


  $("#saab").click(function(){
        $("option").append("<li>Saab Number: <input type="text" name="saabtype" value="Mickey"><br></li>");
    });

$("#opel").click(function(){
        $("option").append("<li>opel type: <input type="text" name="opeltype" value="Mickey"><br></li>");
    });

$("#audi").click(function(){
        $("option").append("<li>audi type: <input type="text" name="auditype" value="Mickey"><br></li>");
    });


});


</script>

</head>
<body>
<select>
  <option value="volvo" id="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" id="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" id="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" id="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

**as @Braza suggested, i don't want to override, i want to append each selected(through dropdown menu) input fields one by one.**

Comment: try on change event instead of click

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery select change event get selected option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750307/jquery-select-change-event-get-selected-option)

Comment: @Braza i want to append not to override

Comment: @Kaw123 then use append when the change event is fired

Comment: You want to append the input in the drop down or on the page?

Comment: Thanks , i figured it out at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this fiddle to demonstrate https://jsfiddle.net/jbzL55ca/3

```
$('select.theSelect').on('change', function (e) {}
```