# jquery context selector vs .find()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is more efficient?

```
var container = $("#container");

// 1
var links1 = container.find("a");

// 2
var links2 = $("a", container);
```

I personally prefer `$("a", container)` because it looks better, but are they different in performance?

Comment: Under the hood are they even different?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about performance advice that should be measured rather than asked.

Comment: The context syntax is marginally slower, although I'm only talking a matter of miliseconds. Regardless of that, I prefer to use it.

Comment: (1) `links2` has slower performance than `links1`, because it's a wrapper for `find`.
(2) `links2` is less legible than `links1`, because it makes `"a"` appear like the parent element, and `container` like the child element that follows.
I personally prefer `container.find("a")`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The context selector `$("a", container)` is converted to find. `find()` will be faster but in most cases this could be ignored. I would go for `find()` as its syntax is quite stright forward for me. This [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342282/jquery-find-versus-context-selection) has performance comparison that would help you deciding which one you would use.