# Toggle one item on a list jquery

Tags: jquery, list

What I want is when one list item is hovered, toggle a div item but just in that list item.

```
$("#posts li").hover(function(){
        $(".right").toggle("fast");

    });
```

I made this but it toggles the divs in all list items and is not what i want. How can I achieve this?. Thank you

Edit HTML:

```
<ol id="posts">
   <li class="post text">
      <div class="right"></div>

   </li>
   <li class="post photo">
      <div class="right"></div>

   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: wee need to see the html, you need to find the `right` element relative to the hovered element mostly `$(this).find('right').toggle("fast");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tadaaaaa:

```
 $("#posts li").hover(function(){
      $(this).find(".right").toggle("fast");
   });
```

By using this you select the currently hovered li, limiting the search to only the divs with `.right` inside the respective li.

Comment: I think it's cheaper to limit context than to use find. Look at my answer.

Comment: @IvanIvanić The joys of programming :D, my pleasure. Here's another test case http://stackoverflow.com/a/9046288/1401094

Comment: Kinda counterintuitive :D (At least to me)

Answer (score 1):

You can limit context to this list item:

```
$("#posts li").hover(function(){
        $(".right", this).toggle("fast");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css only for that:

```
#posts li .right { display:none; }
#posts li:hover .right { display:block; }
```

Comment: Yes, but i want it with an animation as toggle gives. Transitions and animations are not supported in a lot of browsers or they are rendered differently