# Get options of a dynamic select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to get the following code dynamic:

```
var items = $("#scenario_select option");
```

Above should become (with `dropDownObj= $("#scenario_select");` :

```
function someFunction(dropDownObj){
    var items = $(dropDownObj + " option");
    var items = $("#" + dropDownObj + " option");
}
```

This both doesn't work. I did not find any help on that (only without the options tag)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
function someFunction(dropDownObj){
    var items = $('#' + dropDownObj.prop('id') + " option");
}
```

But I suppose a more 'proper' way to do it would be to use find as suggested by @Exception, or use:

```
function someFunction(dropDownObj){
    var items = $("option", dropDownObj);
}
```

Which basically does the same thing as .find(). See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342282/jquery-find-versus-context-selection) SO question for a comparison between the two (tl;dr: They are pretty much equivalent).

To find the number of items (as you noted in the comments) you could also use:

```
function someFunction(dropDownObj){
    var items = $("option", dropDownObj).length;
}
```

Which is a bit shorter than the solution you posted in the comments.

You should also note that since

```
dropDownObj= $("#scenario_select");
```

It is already a jQuery object, and you don't need to wrap it using $. With this in mind you solution becomes:

```
var items = dropDownObj.children('option').length;
```

Comment: Why you want to check `prop` instead of using `find`?

Comment: Why not. Why do you want to use find instead of $('option', dropDownObj); ?

Comment: If you are referring to the downvotes on your question, its not me. I think your answer is correct and will upvote acccordingly.

Comment: i found another solution to my problem. since i wanted to get the same outcome/return value. the question might be gone in the wrong direction. ` var items = $(dropDownObj).children('option').length;` does do the trick to. nonetheless thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
 var dropDownObj = $('#yourDropDownID');
 dropDownObj.find('option')
```