# What exactly does this jQuery selector do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been studying a piece of jQuery script and editing it for my needs for a few days now. It contains the following lines.

```
var newElement = $("#featured-post").clone();
var inputField = $("select", newElement);
```

I just don't understand what exactly the second line does as I haven't seen such a selector before (yes, I'm new to jQuery).

I can guess that it selects "" elements within the cloned element. But I have not read about this method of selection before. Could somebody explain a little bit about this selector? I've done some googling but didn't find anything related to this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's the [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). It selects `select` elements inside of `newElement`

Comment: Thanks a lot, billyonecan. Really appreciate it.

Comment: There's never really any reason to use the context selector (that I know of). Internally, jQuery translates it to `newElement.find('select')` anyway - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342282/jquery-find-versus-context-selection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it simple for you, the below code:

```
$("select", newElement);
```

is same as doing:

```
$(newElement).find("select");
```

So, the selector will look for the `select` element inside the `newElement` cloned element.

Comment: I think it would make it even simpler if you actually explained what the code does.

Answer (score 1):

> ### jQuery( selector [, context ] )
>
> **selector**
>
> > - **Type:** Selector
> > - A string containing a selector expression
>
> **context**
>
> > - **Type:** Element or jQuery
> > - A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context