# Jquery use obj or element for work with DOM?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm a newbie to jquery and I'm trying to do some simple plugin but I've some dubts. Which is the best way to work with elements of a jquery plugin? Use object or element?

```
..
return this.each(function() {
   var obj = $(this);
   var ele = this;

   myFunc.call(undefined, obj);
   myFunc2.call(undefined, ele);
});

function myFunc(obj) {
    obj.find('tr > th').each(function() {
        $(this).html('hallo');
    });
}

function myFunc2(ele) {
    $(ele).find('tr > th').each(function() {
        $(this).html('hallo');
    });
}
```

In addition you can also use this syntax?

```
function myFunc(obj) {
    $('tr > th', obj).each(function() {
        $(this).html('hallo');
    });
}
function myFunc2(ele) {
    $('tr > th', ele).each(function() {
        $(this).html('hallo');
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) either is fine 2) yes you can, it's called the contextual selector and is equivalent to using `find()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342282/jquery-find-versus-context-selection

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - There are performance differences or anything with regard to the first point? Thank you

Comment: Not inherently, no. Operations on a native DOMElement will always be faster than jQuery, but to the detriment of the amount of code required. Whether you're passing around an object or element makes very little difference.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan -Thank you very much!