# show text from only first span inside clickable li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show the text **1a** when li item is clicked but for some reason it shows text **1a 1b 1c** at the same time whereas i am only interested in text inside the span of li clicked. i tried making use of 'this' but no luck yet.
fiddle example is here => https://jsfiddle.net/5x4xbuf9/

```
   $('li.listItem').on('click',function(){
   var showText =  $('span.a').text();
   alert(showText)
   })
   <li class = "listItem"><span class ="a">1a</span><span class ="b">2a</span></li>
   <li class = "listItem"><span class ="a">1b</span><span class ="b">2b</span></li>
   <li class = "listItem"><span class ="a">1c</span><span class ="b">2c</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your jQuery selector some context, by passing a second argument:

```
var showText =  $('span.a', this).text();
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ptnmeo8o/)

Or if you prefer, use `.find()` ([faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9046288/1612146)):

```
var showText =  $(this).find('span.a').text();
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ptnmeo8o/1/)

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/5x4xbuf9/4/

You needed to target current list Item-

```
var showText =  $(this).find('span.a').text();
```