# Call functions using a jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I directly select classes, etc using a variable?

```
var $tbody = $(".tbl-locations-body");

$(".tbl-locations-body a.collapse").hide();
$(".tbl-locations-body tr.child-row").hide();
$(".tbl-locations-body .container").first().hide();
$(".tbl-locations-body .tab-content").hide();
```

I want to use `$tbody` to perform the methods. What is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $tbody = $(".tbl-locations-body");
$("a.collapse", $tbody).hide();
// etc...
```

Explanation:

If you pass $tbody as second parameter into jquery function, you will search only in a scope of that element($tbody), rather than in whole document.

Comment: Would that be $('a.collapse', $tbody).hide(); ?

Comment: Not sure who you want to answer.  This seems to be the best choice as it is a direct select instead of .find().  Thank you!!!

Comment: Is there a difference between using $tbody as the second parameter or using $tbody.find('a.collapse'); ?

Comment: @FirstByte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342282/jquery-find-versus-context-selection

Comment: Thank you all.  It's not often I get a full and complete answer.  Happy Holidays!!!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `find()` method from the `$tbody` jQuery object. Note that you can apply multiple selectors as well to make the calls a one-liner:

```
var $tbody = $(".tbl-locations-body");
$tbody.find('a.collapse, tr.child-row, .container:first, .tab-content').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [*`find()`*](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method - see code below:

```
var $tbody = $(".tbl-locations-body");

$tbody.find("a.collapse").hide();
$tbody.find("tr.child-row").hide();
$tbody.find(".container").first().hide();
$tbody.find(".tab-content").hide();
```

Comment: From what I've read about selectors, isn't it better to use direct select instead of .find()?

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading up on this and although

```
var $tbody = $(".tbl-locations-body");
$("a.collapse", $tbody).hide();
```

looks cleaner, under the hood it's changed to $tbody.find() anyway.  So the better answer is to use the find method to start with - and as Rory pointed out, you can select multiple too.